# Why fprintf prints new line while writing data to file?

Tags: c, file, printf, fgets

I have a simple c code for file read and write. Everything is working with out any error. But I am not able to understand what is happening here. I have added the code below.

```
  int width=3;
  int height=3;
  char v1[3 * width];       
  int j = 0, k = 0; 
  int i = 0;
  k = height;

  FILE *fp = fopen ("file2.txt", "w");
  while (i < height)
  {
      FILE *fval = fopen ("file1.txt", "r");
      j = 0;

      while (j < k)
     {
       fgets (v1, sizeof (v1), fval);
       j++;
     }
     fprintf (fp, "%s", v1);
     k--;
     i++;
     fclose (fval);
  }
  fclose (fp);
```

I have following contents in `file1.txt`

```
101
111
010
```

I expected the contents of `file2.txt` would be

```
010
111
101
```

But after running the code, when I looked at the `file2.txt`, I got following

```
010111
101
```

What is happening here? Why fprintf is printing new line even though there is no new line format specifier in the `fprintf (fp, "%s", v1);` ? Can anybody help me to understand this?

Thanks,

Comment: An [mcve] would help... I guess it's just wrapping main around it and adding includes, but only you can know.

Comment: Step through the program in a debugger and look at what is in `v1` when you get to the `fprintf`. There is a `\n` at the end, and that's where the `\n` is coming from. That `\n` was read by the `fgets`.

Comment: Can't seem to reproduce that exact behavior: https://onlinegdb.com/Y18JHDfaF

Comment: @mediocrevegetable1 Your file1.txt has 4 lines. OP's has only 3. Remove the trailing `\n` from file1.txt.

Comment: @RaymondChen you're right, same thing happening then.

Comment: `fprint` writes a newline, because `fgets` *retains* the newline. Except there wan't one after the original last line, as commented.

Comment: to remove a trailing newline from a string, suggest: `buffer[ strspn( buffer, "\n" ) ] = '\0';`

Comment: OT: when calling `fopen()`, always check (!=NULL) the returned value to assure the operation was successful.  When not successfull (==NULL) then call `perror()` to output your error message and the text reason the system thinks the call failed to `stderr`

Answer (score 3):

Most probably your input file has no new line marker at the end. Then the last line is read without `\n` and so it is printed to the output file.

Answer (score 0):

Your input file has newlines after the first two lines.
fgets will include those newlines into the read.

So when you print those lines, they will have newlines.

The last line doesn't have a newline, so anything printed
after it will be stuck to it.